# Update with two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update table A with data from table B. I thought I could do
 something like:

```
 UPDATE A
 SET A.name = B.name
 WHERE A.id = B.id
```

but alas, this does not work.

Anyone have an idea of how I can do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your query does not work because you have no **FROM** clause that specifies the tables you are aliasing via A/B.

Please try using the following:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.NAME = B.NAME
FROM TableNameA A, TableNameB B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

Personally I prefer to use more explicit join syntax for clarity i.e.

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.NAME = B.NAME
FROM TableNameA A
    INNER JOIN TableName B ON 
        A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: I don't know if you can have the alias for in the SET clause. Might depend on your flavor of SQL, but I believe that since it's a given that you're updating "A" that it's disallowed.

Answer (score 17):

For `Microsoft Access`

```
UPDATE TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
SET A.Name = B.Name
```

Comment: The selected answer didn't work for me on MariaDB. This one did. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

I was scratching my head, not being able to get John Sansom's Join syntax work, at least in `MySQL 5.5.30 InnoDB`.

It turns out that this doesn't work.

```
UPDATE A 
    SET A.x = 1
FROM A INNER JOIN B 
        ON A.name = B.name
WHERE A.x <> B.x
```

But this works:

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B 
    ON A.name = B.name
SET A.x = 1
WHERE A.x <> B.x
```

Comment: The above is SQL-Server, not MySQL ?

Answer (score 2):

The answers didn't work for me with postgresql 9.1+

This is what I had to do (you can check more in the [manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html))

```
UPDATE schema.TableA as A
SET "columnA" = "B"."columnB"
FROM schema.TableB as B
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

You can omit the schema, if you are using the default schema for both tables.

Comment: Same, this is the only thing that worked for me on postgresql