# SQL-Server 2014. UPDATE joining two tables and using table aliases

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, alias

I have two almost identical tables. 
Need to update every `Postal` in TABLE_03 when it's `NULL` 
There's no ID or Primary Key to use so I'm linking these with columns `Link`, `Name` and `PhoneNum` /  ( `Phone` in TABLE_ALL )

Tried SQL:

```
 UPDATE TABLE_03 a
   join TABLE_ALL b 
   ON   a.Link = b.Link,
        a.Name = b.Name,
        a.PhoneNum = b.Phone
   SET a.Postal = b.PostalCode
  WHERE a.Postal IS NULL;
```

SQL Server gives error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
```

Without aliases :

```
  UPDATE TABLE_03 
   join TABLE_ALL 
   ON   TABLE_03.Link = TABLE_ALL.Link,
        TABLE_03.Name = TABLE_ALL.Name,
        TABLE_03.PhoneNum = TABLE_ALL.Phone
   SET TABLE_03.Postal = TABLE_ALL.PostalCode
  WHERE TABLE_03.Postal IS NULL;
```

Gives error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.
```

Comment: please check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044467/how-to-update-two-tables-in-one-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update with two tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068447/update-with-two-tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, mainly the `JOIN ON` clause. It should be like below using `AND` operator

```
UPDATE TABLE_03 a
   join TABLE_ALL b 
   ON   a.Link = b.Link AND
        a.Name = b.Name AND
        a.PhoneNum = b.Phone
   SET a.Postal = b.PostalCode
  WHERE a.Postal IS NULL;
```

With proper `SQL Server` syntax

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Postal = b.PostalCode
FROM TABLE_03 a
   join TABLE_ALL b 
   ON   a.Link = b.Link AND
        a.Name = b.Name AND
        a.PhoneNum = b.Phone   
  WHERE a.Postal IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       UPDATE TABLE_03 
 SET TABLE_03.Postal = TABLE_ALL.PostalCode
 from TABLE_ALL 
 where  TABLE_03.Link = TABLE_ALL.Link AND 
    TABLE_03.Name = TABLE_ALL.NAME AND 
    TABLE_03.PhoneNum = TABLE_ALL.Phone and

   TABLE_03.Postal IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UPDATE a
   SET a.Postal = b.PostalCode
   FROM TABLE_03 a
   join TABLE_ALL b 
   ON   a.Link = b.Link,
        a.Name = b.Name,
        a.PhoneNum = b.Phone
  WHERE a.Postal IS NULL;
```