# MySQL update with select from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 tables.
Companies, Kommuner and Fylker.

The companies table have an empty field `forretningsadresse_fylke` but an other field `forretningsadresse_kommune` with a value.

So basically, I need to fill in `forretningsadresse_fylke`, based on the value of `forretningsadresse_kommune`.

Now, the value of `forretningsadresse_kommune` and the value I want for `forretningsadresse_fylke` is stored in the Kommuner and Fylker tables.

So I wrote this query, but that doesn't seem to work because after 600 seconds the "MySQL server goes away".

```
UPDATE companies, fylker, kommuner
SET companies.forretningsadresse_fylke = (
    SELECT fylkeNavn 
    FROM fylker 
    WHERE fylker.fylkeID = kommuner.fylkeID
)
WHERE companies.forretningsadresse_kommune = kommuner.kommuneNavn
```

Here is what the Kommuner and Fylker tables look like.

Kommuner Table

[image]

Fylker Table

[image]

Companies table
[image]

companies Table

```
            | forretningsadresse_fylke  | forretningsadresse_kommune |
            |===========================|============================|
            |                           |                            |
            |                           |                            |
            |                           |                            |
            |                           |                            |
            |                           |                            |
            |                           |                            |
```

So I was wondering if there was something wrong with the query?
Also, it might be good to mention, the table I try to update (Companies) has over 1 million rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you describe your tables? or at lest `Companies` table

Comment: I edited the post. Now you can see the companies table too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not want `fylker` in the `UPDATE` statement.  You should also be using a proper `join`.  So the first rewrite is:

```
UPDATE companies c JOIN
       kommuner k
       ON c.forretningsadresse_kommune = k.kommuneNavn
    SET c.forretningsadresse_fylke = (SELECT f.fylkeNavn 
                                      FROM fylker f
                                      WHERE f.fylkeID = k.fylkeID
                                     );
```

If we assume a single match in `fylker`, then this is fine.  If there are multiple matches, then you need to choose one.  A simple method is:

```
UPDATE companies c JOIN
       kommuner k
       ON c.forretningsadresse_kommune = k.kommuneNavn
    SET c.forretningsadresse_fylke = (SELECT f.fylkeNavn 
                                      FROM fylker f
                                      WHERE f.fylkeID = k.fylkeID
                                      LIMIT 1
                                     );
```

Note:  This will update all companies that have a matching "kommuner".  If there is no matching "fylker" the value will be set to `NULL`.  I believe this is the intent of your question.

Also, table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Yea, thanks! The last query you built works great! 
I was not sure I could use JOIN statements inside an UPDATE, I though that was only for SELECT. But know I know. I lear something new everyday! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can refer this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-use-join-in-update-query

```
    UPDATE companies c
    JOIN Kommuner k ON c.kommuneID = k.kommuneID
    JOIN fylker f ON f.fylkeID = k.fylkeID
    SET c.forretningsadresse_fylke = f.fylkeNavn
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE companies c
SET companies.forretningsadresse_fylke = (
    SELECT fylkeNavn 
    FROM Commoner k Left join Fylker f ON f.fylkeID = k.fylkeID
    where k.kommuneNavn = c.forretningsadresse_kommune
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE companies
SET companies.forretningsadresse_fylke = fylker.fylkeNavn
FROM companies, fylker, kommuner
WHERE companies.forretningsadresse_kommune = kommuner.kommuneNavn AND fylker.fylkeID = kommuner.fylkeID
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068471/3866134