# Is there a faster alternative to insert into X (select Y from where Z) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
table_a

user_id  score  
1        10     
2        10      
3        10      
5        43      
6        43      
9        20      
10       42    



table_b

user_id  flag
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        1
5        1
6        0 
7        1
```

In the above case, how can I populate the `table_b.flag` to `1` if `user_id` from `table_a` has a (`score > 40`)?

Comment: user_id at table_a & table_b are related ???

Comment: Yes, check INSERT INTO SELECT ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html  , or UPDATE  JOIN.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955718/mysql-update-with-select-from-another-table etc

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I just want find  a faster method than Insert into select, perhaps the update join by mate would do the trick

Comment: Note that you wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: Inserts add new records to a table updates amend existing records they are not interchangeable. Inserts may be slow because indexes have to be maintained and updates may be slow because they aren't appropriate - either way there is not enough information here to provide you with an answer. You should also look at the explain plan for hints.

Comment: "Faster" seems to be a confusing word. Do you mean to insert and update the table_b.flag column directly using one query without having to do insert then update or you just want a faster insert like 1000 rows in 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multi-table `UPDATE` to get the results you want:

```
UPDATE table_b b
JOIN table_a a ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.score > 40
SET b.flag = 1
```

The `JOIN` condition means that only rows in `table_b` where the corresponding `user_id` in `table_a` has a `score > 40` will have their flag set to `1`. If you want to also set flags to `0` if the corresponding `score <= 40`, you can use the condition as the value to `SET` (since MySQL treats booleans as `1` or `0` in a numeric context):

```
UPDATE table_b b
JOIN table_a a ON a.user_id = b.user_id
SET b.flag = a.score > 40
```

For your sample data, the result in `table_b` is the same:

```
user_id     flag
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           1
5           1
6           1
7           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44PnpqGengiCY3mCEqL7bY/0)

Comment: @Victor was this not helpful?