# Syntax error in sql query of copying data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following query :

```
 update event
    set event.Paid = payment.amount
    from event, payment
    where payment.event_id = event.eid
```

The above query gives following error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from event, payment where payment.event_id = event.eid' at line
>   3

Comment: Which database product are you using? MySQL (as stated in your error message, I guess it's that) or sql-server as in your tags?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: You might need see this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068447/update-with-two-tables

Comment: _I am using phpmyadmin..._ phpmyadmin is a tool not a dbms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update with two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068447/update-with-two-tables)

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh still getting this error; [#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from event e, payment p
where e.eid = p.event_id' at line 3]

Answer (score 2):

You join clause is wrong  anyway

You should not use the implicit join syntax based on comma separated  table name and  where 
 you should use  explicit join syntax  (for mysql)

```
update event 
INNER JOIN payment ON  payment.event_id = event.eid
set event.Paid = payment.amount
```