# Update SQL Server table where column matches another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I have these 2 tables:

```
StudentTable      |      ClassTable

StudentId         |      ClassId       
StudentCode       |      StudentCode
StudentName       |      Class
Class             |
```

Currently a `StudentTable` record looks like this:

```
StudentId    StudentCode    StudentName    Class
-------------------------------------------------
1            20221452       James Daniels  Null
```

and a `ClassTable` record looks like

```
ClassId     StudentCode    Class
----------------------------------
1           20221452       A
```

I was wondering if it possible to do an update select for class where `StudentCode` in `ClassTable` matches `StudentCode` in `StudentTable`

I have tried this statement but it looks very wrong and just threw a syntax error

```
  INSERT INTO [StudentTable](Class)
      SELECT Class
      FROM [ClassTable ]
      WHERE StudentCode IN ([StudentTable]) = StudentCode in ([ClassTable])
```

EDIT: turns out I was looking for an update as I had a few records currently existing

Comment: You have an `IN` equal an `IN`; what is that trying to achieve. The syntax of an `IN` is either `{Scalar Expression} IN ({Delimited List of Literal Values})` or `{Scalar Expression}  IN ({SELECT Statement returning single column})`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: [Update with two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068447/update-with-two-tables)

Comment: @Luuk sorry, I did not see that post before

Answer (score 0):

Can use EXISTS keyword

```
 insert into [StudentTable](Class)
  select Class
  FROM [ClassTable ]
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [StudentTable] WHERE StudentTable.StudentCode = ClassTable.StudentCode)
```

For more info about EXISTS keyword, please read this [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

If you want to use IN keyword, you can write a subquery after IN keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use join easily.

```
 insert into [StudentTable] (Class)
 select class from studentable join classtable on
 studentable.StudentCode  =classtable.StudentCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
UPDATE StudentTable
SET StudentTable.Class=ClassTable.Class
FROM StudentTable, ClassTable
WHERE StudentTable.StudentCode=ClassTable.StudentCode;
```

Thank you everyone