# Setting ParentID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

| ID | Desc | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test A | 0 |
| 2 | Test A | 0 |
| 3 | Test A | 0 |
| 4 | Test B | 0 |
| 5 | Test B | 0 |
| 6 | Test B | 0 |

I need help with an SQL Update Script that will take the first distinct Desc, keep the parentID of 0, but make all other instances of the Desc have a ParentID of the first.

So, by the end, it will be:

Sample Result Data:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test A | 0 |
| 2 | Test A | 1 |
| 3 | Test A | 1 |
| 4 | Test B | 0 |
| 5 | Test B | 4 |
| 6 | Test B | 4 |

Comment: How do you know what value is the "parent" and which the "children"? Why is `3` not a child of `2` and why is `4` not a child of `5`? With what you have a windowed `MIN` would work, but I somehow doubt that is it *real* solution.

Comment: MIN might work as honestly, that would suffice.  Can this be done in one statement or would I need to use a cursor?

Comment: 1 statement... no <shudder> cursor.  Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068447/update-with-two-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desc is a reserved word so it is a bad choice, the rest can be solved with a cte to get the parent of all Desc

```
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT MIN(ID) min_id, [Desc] FROM TableA GROUP BY [Desc])
SELECT [ID], ta.[Desc], CASE WHEN ID = min_id THEN ParentID ELSE min_id END as ParentID 
  FROM TableA ta JOIN CTE ON ta.[Desc] = CTE.[Desc]
```

| ID | Desc | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test A | 0 |
| 2 | Test A | 1 |
| 3 | Test A | 1 |
| 4 | Test B | 0 |
| 5 | Test B | 4 |
| 6 | Test B | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BDlGN2NR)

An Update is actually also easy

```
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT MIN(ID) min_id, [Desc] FROM TableA GROUP BY [Desc])
, CTE2 AS (SELECT [ID], CASE WHEN ID = min_id THEN ParentID ELSE min_id END as ParentID 
  FROM TableA ta JOIN CTE ON ta.[Desc] = CTE.[Desc])
UPDATE TableA SET ParentID =  (SELECT ParentID FROM CTE2 WHERE ID = TableA.ID)
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

| ID | Desc | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test A | 0 |
| 2 | Test A | 1 |
| 3 | Test A | 1 |
| 4 | Test B | 0 |
| 5 | Test B | 4 |
| 6 | Test B | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XPD4xfww)

Comment: Worked great!  This is the actual SQL : WITH CTE as (
  SELECT MIN(JobTitleID) min_id, JobTitleDesc FROM JobTitles GROUP BY JobTitleDesc)
SELECT JobTitleID, ta.JobTitleDesc, CASE WHEN JobTitleID = min_id THEN ParentJobTitleID ELSE min_id END as ParentJobTitleID 
  FROM JobTitles ta JOIN CTE ON ta.JobTitleDesc = CTE.JobTitleDesc -- how do I turn this into an UPDATE for the JobTitles Table?

Comment: @ScottScriver i updated my answer, you can change the column names as before

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so very much for your help and quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this **without any self-joins**, using a window function

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      MIN(a.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY a.[Desc]) AS min_id
    FROM TableA a
)
UPDATE cte
SET ParentId = min_id
WHERE ID <> min_id;
```